# boto3: Get version ID and support callbacks on object upload

Tags: python, boto3

I would like to upload a file to S3 with a progress callback as it uploads, and also get the version ID of the object I just uploaded.

[`client.put_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/put_object.html) returns the version ID, but doesn't have a callback parameter:

```py
client = boto3.client('s3')
response = client.put_object(...)
version_id = response['VersionId']
```

[`client.upload_file`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/upload_file.html) *does* have a callback parameter, but it doesn't return anything:

```py
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.upload_file(..., Callback=my_callback)
```

The only thing I can think of is to tag my objects with some unique value, then after uploading find the version of the object with that unique value tagged. But that sounds overly complicated for what I'm trying to do.

Is there some API call I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a reasonable solution by wrapping the client to store the upload result and using [S3Transfer](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.S3Transfer) directly. I can then get the upload result out of the wrapped client object.

```py
class ClientWrapper:
    def __init__(self, client):
        self._client = client
        self.upload_result = None

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._client, name)

    def put_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.upload_result = self._client.put_object(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.upload_result

    def complete_multipart_upload(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.upload_result = self._client.complete_multipart_upload(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.upload_result

client = boto3.client('s3')
wrapped = ClientWrapper(client)
transfer = S3Transfer(wrapped)
transfer.upload_file(..., callback=my_callback)
version_id = wrapped.upload_result['VersionId']
```